# Aerodrome category, certification?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, airport-design, airport-operations

I need to know how you tell the certification of new airport just built? how can you tell if airport is certified for International flights or not? approved for intl flights or not meeting requirements?
I find this recent airport in Egypt HESX with regional flights approved, yet it has no lights and it operates only during day time, so is it approved for intl flights or not?
[Sphinx Airport Map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Sphinx+International+Airport/@30.1144967,30.8912312,6586m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x145858b53f7c1985:0x7686c83eb4e20600!8m2!3d30.1159462!4d30.9108083)

Comment: For what it's worth, HESX is adjacent to and shares infrastructure with the Egyptian military's Cairo West Air Base, which has been a destination for international flights for years. I took U.S. troops in and out of there from and to the U.S. in the 1990s. The flights were always during the day, never at night. We always assumed, whether correctly or not, that the military wished to keep the base dark at night to make it more difficult to find and attack.

Comment: Thanks Terry for your input, yes i understand its shared airfield, Egypt is opening up new regional hubs taking advantage of per-existed military airbase, i just find it very weird the new expansion is too small to accommodate intl operations, few taxi ways, 24 m width which wont be able to receive wide body aircrafts, limited bay etc...no cat2 or cat 3 .... knowing the civilian section wont use same rwys as military ones, and i believe with now days technology its bit stupid not to have lights on to avoid detection :) specially for civilian operations. i cant find zaairport category anywhere

Comment: Some information specific to taxiways in [ICAO Aerodrome Design Manual, Part 2](https://skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/3090.pdf) p9. (runways are in part 1)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Any airport can be used for an international flight. Do you mean commercial airline scheduled service? Also, there is no requirement that an airport be open at night for it to host commercial scheduled airline flights, domestic or international.